# Problema con ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, puertos

es la primera vez que configuro un servidor con ubuntu, en el tengo dos aplicaciones en php con dos frameworks diferentes, una tiene el dominio principal y la otra con un subdominio, una de esas aplicaciones la del subdominio debe tomar datos vía post de la otra aplicación por medio de una api ubicada en el mismo servidor. Pero no sé cómo realizar el llamado, lo intente por la url pero laravel me indica que la url no existe, no sé si se deba a que ambas usan el mismo puerto, en este caso no se como configurar para que el subdominio solo funcione por un puerto en específico, o no sé si toca configurar algo más del servidor, Agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Después de averiguar por varias preguntas en este mismo sitio pero en ingles encontré la solución en este apartado: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412069/can-i-do-a-curl-request-to-the-same-server

El usuario Kevin Nguyen dio con la respuesta. Era solo configurar la ip local al dominio donde está la api en el archivo host.

Muchas gracias.